# How to Boot with no splash screen

Tags: 11.10, boot, plymouth

*Ubuntu 11.10 desktop up to date (Gnome 3)*

To prevent answers in haste, please notice that

- `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""` is set in `/etc/default/grub`
- Tried also `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=off"`

This removes most of the Ubuntu splash screen and shows most of the messages.

However, just after the BIOS launches the Operating system, Ubuntu starts by "preparing" the splash: the screen is ubuntu-colored for about 1 second (plain color, looks somewhat like the default color after a login). During this 1 second some messages are displayed that cannot be seen.

I wouldn't care much, but unfortunately during 50% of the boots, and during this very second, Ubuntu asks something... don't know what since I cannot see the messages. So I do Control-D (tried ^D once and it worked, so I keep doing it again) and the messages page is back and immediately cleared (the messages before the ^D can be seen for a split second - i.e. can't see them) and Ubuntu resumes the boot normally.

Unfortunately `dmesg` doesn't show what was asked during that second. Nothing in the logs. But I'd like to know what happens. So the question:

Is there a way to prevent that pre-splash colored page that hides the messages for 1 second to appear?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `noplymouth` to that line, then updating grub with `sudo update-grub`.
On the second thought, if you just want to see what it says, try the recovery option from Grub.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work.

Comment: The recovery options is not the solution, but it helps to see the messages, so +1. For info, I fixed the initial problem thanks to http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11388915&postcount=18